# Using PnPListItem command doesn't display all the columns of the list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am uising Powershell with SharePoint Online.
I have a list with 3 columns: Name, Emailadres, Title
When I use the command to display the list:

Get-PnPListItem -List "test"

I get only the Id, Title and GUID columns

How to I get the columns Id, Name, Emailadres, Title of the list test displayed in PS.

Gr.p

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can specify parameters after Get-PnListItem.

For example, you want to get columns Id, Name, Emailadres, Title of the list test.

You can refer to such a command like this:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List "test" - Fields "Title", "Name", " Emailadres ","Column3","GUID"
```

More information:

[Get-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: This is not true. Even writing it as (Get-PnPListItem -List "test" - Fields "Title", "Name", " Emailadres ","Column3","GUID").fieldValues, you do get all metadata for each listitem and would need loop through each item and get the required values.

Comment: I have read in the question that is similar as mine that it is not possible with this commandlet. The code above that is posted doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if *Emailadres* is just misspelled but here we go.

```
$items = (Get-PnPListItem -List "test"-Fields "Name","Emailadres","Title").fieldValues

$array = @()

foreach ($item in $items) {

    $row = new-object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $item.Name;
        Emailadres = $item.Emailadres;
        Title = $item.Title;
    }

    $array += $row 
}

$array
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer!